# Java: Multiple columns in combo boxes

Tags: java, netbeans, combobox

I'm quite new to Java, so I'm using NetBeans to create my application. I was wondering if there was a relatively simple way to create columns within a combo box? 
I've tried using tabs but the tabs show up as spaces. Ideally, I'd like some sort of character that could align the next column, but anything would be great.
Thanks!

Comment: Could you just use a fixed width font for the text in your combo boxes, and insert the correct number of spaces at each position?

Comment: Ty's not somoething the combo box is really good at/for. You cod take a look at [this example](http://java-swing-tips.blogspot.com.au/2008/08/multi-column-jcombobox.html)

Comment: The fixed width font idea is fantastic - it also makes it easier to read input later because instead of finding the start of the next column using indexOf as I'd planned, I already know where it starts. Thanks David!